# Tool for edit lvm.conf file

Tags: parsing, automation, config, lvm

is there any **lvm.conf** editor?

I'm trying to set *global_filter*, *use_lvmtad* and some other options, currently using sed:

```sh
sed -i /etc/lvm/lvm.conf \
      -e "s/use_lvmetad = 1/use_lvmetad = 0/" \
      -e "/^ *[^#] *global_filter/d" \
      -e "/^devices {/a\        global_filter = [ \"r|/dev/drbd.*|\", \"r|/dev/dm-.*|\", \"r|/dev/zd.*|\" ]"
```

but I don't like this too much, is there any better way?

I found only [lvmconfig](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/lvmconfig.8.html) tool, but it can only display certain configuration sections, and can't edit them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that [augtool](https://linux.die.net/man/1/augtool) is exactly what I was looking for.

These two packages should be enough to proper processing `lvm.conf` file:

```
apt install augeas-tools augeas-lenses
```

**Example usage:**

```sh
augtool print /files/etc/lvm/lvm.conf
```

And you should get the whole parse tree on stdout.

If the parser fails you won’t get any output, print the error message using:

```sh
augtool print /files/etc/lvm/lvm.conf/error
```

The augtool equivalent for the sed command from the original question:

```sh
augtool -s <<EOT
set /files/etc/lvm/lvm.conf/global/dict/use_lvmetad/int "0"
rm /files/etc/lvm/lvm.conf/devices/dict/global_filter
set /files/etc/lvm/lvm.conf/devices/dict/global_filter/list/0/str "r|^/dev/drbd.*|"
set /files/etc/lvm/lvm.conf/devices/dict/global_filter/list/1/str "r|/dev/dm-.*|"
set /files/etc/lvm/lvm.conf/devices/dict/global_filter/list/2/str "r|/dev/zd.*|"
EOT
```

Answer (score 0):

If you using Ubuntu variant then you can use the LVM GUI to configure and manage the LVM. Refer [this](https://www.howtogeek.com/127246/linux-sysadmin-how-to-manage-lvms-with-a-gui/) link

Comment: Thanks, but I needed just tiny tool for automate lvm configuration.